# Magento 2 - Create Customer Account too slow

Tags: php, linux, magento, magento2

I am a new developer of Magento 2.

I set up Magento 2 in my local server (WAMP) and the process time of create a customer account below 10 second. It is a acceptable response time.

However, after I set it in a Linux server, the system need 1 minute to process after clicking create account button.

It is not acceptable for a small website. Can someone tell me what should I do to reduce the time during create account?

Comment: What kind of application do you want to develope? - Maybe magento is not the right software to use. Magento is a heavy software and you have to manage a lot of things there. What are your server specs?

Comment: my company is going to do a small e-commerce platform and we confirmed to choose Magento. I think it is not related to server spec since our company hosting other system in same server.

Comment: Some related informations: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152221/why-magento-2-is-extremely-slow

Comment: Please tell me your server specs. Server are a big thing in perfomance ...

Comment: Other page is quite fast but create customer account need to wait long time...

Comment: As you told: You host more things on this server. If you have not good specs, this can cause a problem. About the information you gave, there could be a slow sql perfomance. You use MySQL or something else?

Comment: yes. we are using mysql for magento use

Comment: Is the same thing in production mode?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I found the problem about this question. After clicking "Create Account", It will send a welcome email to customer. However, the email server setting is wrong so that magento will wait 60 seconds to get back the response. Thanks.